# Can I declare a function inside of the parameter of another function in PHP?

Tags: php

I am writing helper functions that allow me to build tables quickly.  I have a function called responsive_table that accepts two parameters:  headings, and rows.  The rows are dynamic and are pulled from a database.  I build an array of rows with a foreach loop because some of the db table rows don't match the contents or order of the html table... some of the cells in the html table contain combinations of db columns, etc. and can't be displayed directly from the db.  None of the rows in my HTML table array are being displayed.  Nothing from inside of the function that's being declared in the function parameter is being displayed.  Here's my code:

```
<?php
$output = responsive_table(array('<input type="checkbox" name="all">', 'Thumbnail', 'Title', 'Location', 'Author', 'Date Submitted', 'Actions'), function(){
    foreach($listing_results as $listing){
        $listings[] = array(
            '<input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="'.$listing['listing_id'].'">',
            '<img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="Thumbnail">',
            $listing['title'],
            $listing['location'],
            anchor('members/modify/'.$listing['member_id'], $listing['display_name']),
            date($setting['date_format'], $listing['date_submitted']),
            array(
                array(
                    'title' => 'Modify Listing',
                    'color' => 'primary',
                    'href' => 'listings/modify/'.$listing['listing_id'],
                    'text' => '<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>'
                ),
                array(
                    'title' => 'Delete Listing',
                    'color' => 'danger',
                    'href' => 'listings/delete/'.$listing['listing_id'],
                    'text' => '<i class="fa fa-eraser"></i>',
                    'confirm' => true
                )
            )
        );
    }
    return $listings;                       
});

 echo $output;

function responsive_table($headings = array(), $rows = array(), $sortable = false){

    $output = '
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table data-sortable class="table">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                ';

    if(count($headings) > 0){

        foreach($headings as $heading){

            $output .= '
                                                <th>'.$heading.'</th>';

        }

    }

    $output .= '
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>';

    if(count($rows) > 0){

        foreach($rows as $row){

            $output .= '
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>'.$row.'</td>
                                            </tr>';

        }

    }

    $output .= '
                                    </table>
                                </div>';

    return $output;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any valid PHP code may appear inside a function, even other functions and class definitions. What it looks like your trying to do is work with anonymous functions, also known as closures. Here is a link that might help you out with this [PHP anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: So anonymous functions are the same as closures and this link explains this further with detailed examples. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Yes, why is the $rows variable in my responsive_table function returning object(Closure)[21] instead of the array that I return in the function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are looking for is a http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

Comment: So when I dumped the $rows variable from inside my responsive_table function, it returns object(Closure)[21]  what exactly do I do with that? lol

Comment: you were asking if you could insert a function into another as a parameter right? Closures were created exactly for that. Let's say you do this function1($parameter1, $parameter2) {echo $parameter2($parameter1);} so what is going on here (assuming that $parameter2 is a colsure) is that you are passing the first parameter to the function that you called function1 with like so: $arg = function($fn2_pm1) {// do something}; function1('string', $arg). Hope that helped